# Calling python program within python program which takes paramters

Tags: python

Suppose I do this

```
os.system("python test.py --desc=" +str(description))
```

Where description is a body of text. When I run this, it doesnt bind the entire string with this input. For example if

```
description = "hello world"
```

I run this, and it will see the input as just hello and then error out on "world" as an unintended parameter.

Is there a simple way which I can pass this entire thing to it without such issue?

Comment: Try a format string: `os.system('python test.py --desc="{}"'.format(description))` I think you'd have to wrap the argument in quotes.

Comment: You need to enclose the string in additional quotes: `"python ... --desc=\"" + str(description) + "\""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `call` function from the `subprocess` module does what `os.system` does, but it takes a list of arguments instead of a string. If you use it you don't need to quote your command string. For example, you're code could be rewritten to:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python", "test.py", "--desc=" + str(description))
```

and you wouldn't have to do anything special to `description`. It would be passed in to `sys.argv[1]`, even it if contained white space.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
os.system('python test.py --desc="' + str(description) + '"')
```

Since you would be using `python test.py --desc="Hello World"` when running the script from the command line, you need to include those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers only work if you know that your input won't ever contain quotes or other special characters. A better solution, though still not perfect, is:

```
os.system('python test.py --desc="' + str(description).encode('string_escape') + '"')
```

That should replace `"` with `\"`, newlines with `\n`, etc. I'm not sure how well escapes for more unusual control characters will match up with the shell, though.